# Parse an UTC time, and render it as a local-timezone time

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, timezone

I have a string named `utctime` which is a date/time in UTC timezone:

```
import time
utctime = "2017-01-12 08:38:28"      # UTC
t = time.strptime(utctime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

**How to render this date/time as local-server-timezone?** This:

```
time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", t)
# "2017-01-12 08:38:28"
```

doesn't work obviously because I get the UTC time again.

Is it possible with just `time` or `datetime` module and nothing else?

*PS: I'm myself in UTC+1.*

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to stick with just time or datetime, you would have to implement your own timezones (D:).  Here is a way to do it using pytz.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz    
utc_time = datetime.utcnow()
tz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')

utc_time =utc_time.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)   
pst_time=utc_time.astimezone(tz)
print pst_time
```

More information on the library is [here](http://pythonhosted.org/pytz/).